# Show alert instead of scheduled notification if the app is currently opened

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have an app that schedules a bunch of notifications (user has to answer questionnaires) locally using `AlarmManager`. The notification should show at certain points in the future.

I schedule the notifications like this:

```
private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, int delay, int scheduleId, int notificationId) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationPublisher.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationId);
        notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.INTENT, notification);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, scheduleId, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, delay);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```

The intent is received by a `BroadcastReceiver` that calls `notify` on the notification attached to the intent.

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String INTENT = "notification";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.hasExtra(INTENT)) {
            NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

            Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(INTENT);
            int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);

            notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine so far. The problem that I'm facing is that I only want to show the notification if the app is currently not open/shown. If it's open I want to show an `AlertDialog` instead.

I know that it might be a better idea to put only the plain content of the notification into the intent and only build it when it should be displayed and I want to refactor that later on.

My main problem is, how do I determine in the `onReceive` of my broadcast receiver if the app is currently showing to decide if a notification or an alert should be displayed?

Or is there an entirely different approach that might work better (for example using `WorkManager`)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can handle it on your BroadcastReceiver

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (isForeground(context)) 
            // AlertDialog
        else 
            // Notification
        
    }

public boolean isForeground(Context mContext) {

        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.AppTask> tasks = activityManager.getAppTasks();

        if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
            ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).getTaskInfo().topActivity;
            return topActivity.getPackageName().equals(mContext.getPackageName());
        }

        return true;
    }
```